# Remove a string inside a cell in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to delete a certain string in a cell in MS Access, whether in a column or in the whole table. I know that I can do this using plain old *Find and Replace* but in this case it is not economical for my thousand-row table.

For example,

- remove all `Unknown` values from all columns.
- remove the string "dollars" from the values in column `price` ie. if the cell contains "34 dollars", it will just be "34".

Can this be done in SQL and how?

Comment: An UPDATE query is the way to modify table contents (if thats what you mean by *cells*); http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/update-data-by-using-a-query-HA010076527.aspx

Comment: There are a range of string manipulation function which can be used in Access: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/ and http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1143872&seqNum=6 are useful resources to get you started.  It will help your chances of getting assistance if you provide an example of your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your query will run within an Access session, the second goal is easy.  You can `Replace` *dollars* with a zero-length string.

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET price = Replace(price, 'dollars', '');
```

You could use the same strategy for the first goal, but may decide it makes more sense to examine the datatypes of the table's fields and only `UPDATE` those which are text or memo.

Comment: Is it possible to change `price` into something that will represent all the fields regardless of their type?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  Please try again.

Comment: Thanks. All of my fields have the value `Unknown` in one of the rows, I am trying to change this value into a `''` since Find and Replace takes time to do it.

Comment: If you know the name of a field which might contain *Unknown*, you can execute an `UPDATE` like `UPDATE YourTable
SET price = Replace(YourFieldName, 'Unknown', '');`  However, Access SQL does not support a generalized method which says *"look in every field in this table and substitute a zero-length string for 'Unknown'".*  Is that what you're asking for? (Sorry, I'm puzzled.)

Comment: Yes, it's the latter I was asking for. Thank you for all the help!