# Remove entire cell if it contians certain string MS-Access 2016

Tags: sql, string, ms-access

I am trying to delete/replace all cells of a field in MS-Access 2016 which contain a certain string (in my case a "<" & ">"). 
This would be no problem if only the string itself needed to be deleted/replaces ([Remove a string inside a cell in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118011/remove-a-string-inside-a-cell-in-ms-access))
but I would like to delete/replace the entire cell if the criteria is met.
Example:
**Field**

```
<br>I like food
I also like food
Nice to meet you <br>
```

Result:

```
I also like food
```

As you can see, the number of characters as well as the number of words and blanks vary from cell to cell. The only thing they have in common is "<" & ">".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Removing a cell is the same as setting it to the empty string.  Does that help?

Comment: @Hogan But how do I do this if I only want to empty those strings which contain e certain string and keep the others?

Comment: you do an update with a where clause thta defines what cells you want to change.

Comment: Does it need to be both `<` and `>`?  Will you ever have a `<` without a `>` that you want to keep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect by saying cell you mean the field of a table.
So you want to set fields of a table to null if they contain a `<` and a `>`.

So this is what you want:

```
Update YourTable Set YourField = Null Where YourField Like '*<*' And YourField Like '*>*'
```

If you explicitly want to set the field to an empty string use this:

```
Update YourTable Set YourField = '' Where YourField Like '*<*' And YourField Like '*>*'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return records that do not contain a `<` character.

```
SELECT MyText
FROM Table1
WHERE INSTR(MyText, "<")=0
```

this will delete the whole record where `MyText` contains a `<`:

```
DELETE *
FROM Table1 
WHERE INSTR(MyText, "<")>0
```

Probably better to use the `LIKE` method that @UnhandledException uses rather than `INSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
update tablename
set cell = ''
where contains(cell,'<') and contains(cell,'>')
```

if contains is not supported you can use

```
where cell like '*<*' and cell like '*>*'
```

Comment: I don't think `contains` is part of MS-Access SQL.

Comment: oh good point @DarrenBartrup-Cook -- that is in sql server.  Probably have use like as unhandled did.

Comment: Not really down-votable though - no idea who did that.

Comment: Not me for sure. I also don't understand that.

Comment: :/  I guess I could delete it, but I don't really care.  I got points to spare.

Comment: lol, true.  I don't get the time these days to build up a good score (a kill-streak?) :)